# Convertion of csv file to json file in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Can anyone help me how to fetch a blob (.csv) and convert it to a (.json) in Azure Data Factory Pipeline using custom activites?

Comment: Just a note, this is an old post and I think referring to ADF v1.  You can now copy a .csv and convert it to .json in ADF v2 just using the [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do not have a native csv-->JSON converter.  However, one of our solution partners has built one (be aware this is not a supported code base).  You can read how to do it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shwetasblogs/archive/2015/05/06/solving-the-big-legacy-data-problem-using-azure-data-factory.aspx  and there is sample code to create a custom .NET activity for ADF in the GitHub repo that is referenced in the instruction blog.

You will need to create an ADF custom activity to run the converter. There are instructions in our documentation on how to do that https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/. Also, caveat that the code in the repo may need to be updated for VS 2015 or other changes, but you can use it as a starting point.  Hope that helps!